# How do I center the elements from my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want the buttons from my navbar to appear on the center of the navigation bar, but I can only seem to make them appear on the left or right. How do I center them? Here's my CSS code:

```
body{
 background-color:#d9dbdd;
}

#nav {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 999999;
 position:fixed;
}

#nav li {
 float: left;
}

#nav li a {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #111;  
}

.active {
 background-color: #007ed8;
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ctjhvz6u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `float: left` rule you have declared on you `#nav li` and instead add `display: inline-block`, then declare `text-align: center` on `#nav`.

You won't be able to align anything center while a `float` rule is declared on the element in question. Any element you have styled as `display: inline-block` can be horizontally aligned center if you declare `text-align: center` on the containing parent element.

```css
body {
  background-color: #d9dbdd;
}

#nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999999;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #007ed8;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav" class="bg-inverse navbar-inverse">
  <li><a class="active" href="#despre">Despre mine</a></li>
  <li><a href="#educatie">Educatie</a></li>
  <li><a href="#aptitudini">Aptitudini</a></li>
  <li><a href="#experienta">Experienta</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ctjhvz6u/1/

Answer (score 2):

Remove this:

```
#nav li {
  float: left;
}
```

And add to `#nav`

```
display: flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content: center;
```

I suggest you to use

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```

To be sure that the code runs on the most browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```
#nav {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: center; /* centers them horizontally */
}
```